# Is the use of divergence theorem valid in a region whose divergence blows to infinity on its surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, divergence-theorem

Say we've a vector function $\vec{D}$
defined in some region on whose **boundary** it's divergence goes to infinity and *inside* we have $\nabla \cdot \vec{D}=\rho$.

Then is it valid to use the gauss divergence theorem here? That is can we say :

$\int_{V}(\nabla \cdot \vec{D}) d v=\int_{V} \rho d v$ , hence

$\int_{s} D\cdot d s =\int_{V} \rho d v$ if the surface integral converges.

Comment: Can you do estimates to be sure that the improper integral actually converges?

Comment: Yes I know beforehand that the surface integral converges

Comment: That depends a little bit on what you mean by "divergence". If you mean "pointwise divergence", then $\vec{D}$ given by the gradient of the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation with the domain being $\{ x : 0<\| x \| \leq 1 \}$ is, in a sense, a counterexample (in dimension greater than one, of course).

Comment: Actually, I was asking about the triple integral of divergence. That is an improper integral.  Can you give the example you have in mind for $\vec D$?